# Detect a pattern in time series data

Tags: time-series

I have the following time serie data and I need to detect the following pattern:
- a 1st spike above a given value
- a 2nd spike close to the given value

What defines "a spike" is that its value is x% above the surrounding spikes.

[image: Time serie data]

I would like to use python (numpy and pandas modules) to detect these.

As a background, the goal is to trigger an action when the second spike is detected (outlined in red in the attached image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scipy.signal`'s [`finds_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) should have most of what you need.

With the `height` argument you can set a minimum threshold to get the first peak.

With the `prominence` argument you should be able to approximate the second peak. This requires [`peak_prominences`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_prominences.html#scipy.signal.peak_prominences).

> The prominence of a peak measures how much a peak stands out from the
>   surrounding baseline of the signal and is defined as the vertical
>   distance between the peak and its lowest contour line.